# LTV analysis in SQL, group users by month of user creation then sum their all-time revenue

Tags: mysql, sql

As above, I'm trying to create a query that buckets users by their creation month, but then sums their all-time revenue.

E.g. 5 users were created in June. Assume all purchases are £10 for simplicity. So their LTV just looking at June is just £10 (£50/5). Lets say 3 of those users also purchased in July. So, their LTV (looking from June to July) Should be £50 + £30 divided by 5, so £16.

The query I'm currently trying is below, but I'm pretty sure it's just returning the AOV of new users in their month of joining - or something similar to that:

```
select
date_format(from_unixtime(Users.creation_date),'%Y %M') 
as'Cohort_Join_Date',
sum(Orders.Revenue) as 'Order_Revenue',
count(Users.id) as 'Number_of_New_Users',
sum(Orders.Revenue) / count(Users.id) as 'LTV'

from Users
join Orders ON Orders.userid = Users.id

where Users.creation_date > '1496275200'

group by Cohort_Join_Date
order by Users.creation_date ASC;
```

So using the example text above, I have 2 tables, Users and Orders. For the sake of the example, Users has 2 fields: (id, creation_date). Orders has 2 as well: (userid, revenue).

Using the example data I wrote in the second paragraph, looking between June and July, users created in june made 5 * £10 orders in June and 3 * £10 orders in July. Lets say July had 7 new users, also each purchasing £10. The  output should look like:

June 2017: £16
July 2017: £10

Any suggestions/help on how to solve this would be much appreciated!

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  Your explanation is okay but it doesn't show what the data looks like.

Comment: Yes add some sample and expected data. How does one get to know a new user? Is there an column that is used to do so?

Comment: Ok, tried to add some more info, does that help?

Comment: just put the output you get with your query on 2-3 lines and the output you want